# get nested keys in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to python and I am writing a testing program.  I have generated a dictionary of results and now I want to analyze them.  A sample of my dictionary looks like this.

```
results = {
        1: {'rd': 28, 'rm': 28, 'pd': 41, 'pm': 41},
        2: {'rd': 40, 'rm': 40, 'pd': 18, 'pm': 18},
        3: {'rd': 147, 'rm': 36, 'pd': 241, 'pm': 290},
        }
```

I am trying get get the `'rd'` keys and add them together.

I understand

```
results[1].values()
```

gets me

```
dict_values([28, 28, 41, 41])
```

But I can't figure out how to just get the 28 so I can iterate over the list.

What am I missing?  On a side note I am trying to dig deep to learn programing so at this time I am trying to avoid using libraries.

Comment: You mean you want `results[1]['rd']`? You should read https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Comment: Thank you I got confused when I tried that and add the .values() to the end of it and that is what brought me here.

Comment: When you get to what loop? There is not currently a loop in your question. Also, dictionaries are *unordered*, so *"first"* has no sensible meaning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if  you `mydict.values` you will get the dictionary values, you dictionary is nested, so when you take values it also the dictionary.

```
[ x['rd'] for x in results.values() ]
```

output:

```
[28, 40, 147]
```

you want to sum just use `sum` function

```
sum([ x['rd'] for x in results.values() ])
```

output:

```
  215
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting the `values` of the nested dictionaries is useless, because they can be in any order.  You need to grab the nested dictionary itself and then extract the value by using the key name:

```
rd_sum = 0
for sub_dict in results:
    rd_sum += sub_dict['rd']
```